# Apache Camel single route to get message from multiple source

Tags: apache-camel

I need to write a single Apache Camel route to

1. Receive Message (which contain File-Location) from Active-MQ JMS-Queue.
2. Using location in received-message from JMS-Queue read file content.
3. Send that file content to another Active-MQ JMS-Queue.

I can write two separate route 1) To get message from Active-MQ and 
  2) To read from a file in folder using static file-name and send to JMS-queue. 
But my requirement is to read the content only from those files, for which I am getting details from JMS queue. Means reading content from files is selective and based on condition.

Following is the sample Java DSL Route configuration I required for it.

```
from("activemq:queue:filelocationQueue")
 .from("file://<<File-Location from JMS-Queue>>?noop=true")
   .convertBodyTo(String.class)
      .to("activemq:queue:fileContent");
```

I know it is not possible to use two "from" inside a route. But how can I put this kind of logic using Apache Camel?

Guys please suggest me the solution, I am also ready to use two Camel route to implement this logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Camel's ConsumerTemplate inside Processor to get what you need like this:

```java
    from("activemq:queue:filelocationQueue")
    .process(new Processor() {

        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

            // "file://<<File-Location from JMS-Queue>>?noop=true"
            String fileLocation = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

            ConsumerTemplate template = getContext().createConsumerTemplate();
            // This is like your second "from". Use 2 second timeout (2000 ms).
            Exchange fileExchange = template.receive(fileLocation,2000);
            exchange.getOut().setBody(fileExchange.getIn().getBody());
            template.doneUoW(fileExchange);
        }
    })
    .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
    .to("activemq:queue:fileContent");
```

Above assumes that the message body received from the filelocationQueue contains exact path to the file to be consumed, e.g. *file:/home/user/input?noop=true&**fileName**=file.txt*. Note that the only way you can consume *only* one file is to use **fileName** URI option. Otherwise you will be consuming all the files in that folder.

Comment: Yes with minor change it works fine for me. I am able to define new endpoint dynamically using my message from JMS-Queue. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Content Enricher EIP](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) with its pollEnrich method:

```
from("direct:start")
  .pollEnrich("file:inbox?fileName=data.txt")
  .to("direct:result");
```

The URI for pollEnrich is computed dynamically using values from the current Exchange.

Comment: I tried it and it is a good option. But in this case, I was not able to provide "Parent Folder" dynamically using received absolute file path.  Looks like it is required to hard-code parent-folder for example in your case it is "inbox". Only fileName is dynamic and can be generated and provided dynamically at runtime. Thanks for helping me.